# Math with typescript array - Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I'm really confused about how to approach this:

I have an array like this:

```
arr=["X12","Z1","Y7","Z22","X4","X8"]
```

I wish to perform mathematical functions on the elements such that:

Each element starting with "X" will have a fixed value `5`, hence if there are `3` elements starting with "X" inside the array `arr`, it should go as : `(fixed value of X) multiplied by (No. of "X" element occurrences inside array) = 5x3 = 15.`

I tried something like this to calculate the no. of occurrences of "X" element but it doesn't work.

```
var xcounter = 0;
calculate(){
          this.arr.forEach(element => {
            if(this.arr.includes("X"))
            {
              this.xcounter++; //this doesn't give me no. of X element occurrences though.
            }
          });
        }
```

What would be a clutter-free way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to use array [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with string [`startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) method.

```js
var arr = ["X12","Z1","Y7","Z22","X4","X8"];
var valueX = 5;

var occurencesX = arr.filter(item => item.startsWith('X')).length;

console.log(occurencesX * valueX);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this

1. loop in to your array
2. Find how many time you found values which has X in starts

```js
var  arr=["X12","Z1","Y7","Z22","X4","X8"]
let total = 0
arr.forEach(
  (row) =>{
        total =  row.startsWith('X')? total + 1 : total
  }
)

console.log(total * 5)
```